# restart a failed task sequence

Tags: sccm

When using a Task Sequence to reimage a PC, is it possible to restart the Task Sequence if an error occurs during one of the steps from where it failed?

The only other options that I'm aware of are to restart the whole Task Sequence, duplicate the Task Sequence and remove the steps that completed, or run the rest of the programs manually. None of those are great options!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of.

SCCM utilizes an image. However, what gives it more malleability is that this image is done through packages. In Ghost, you create an exact like-ness of an image and then replicate said image to another machine. In SCCM, you can create a variety of different packages, and then assign those to a task sequence. However, this is a build (& capture) technique.

That's why if it fails, SCCM can only track what caused the failure and then desists anymore action and will not have a "save state" of sorts and you will have to re-run the image. Just like if a package fails, you have to re-run the advertisement to that specific machine and cannot ask it to pick up where the installation left off.